# Close and open another div after the loop increments by 3 every time

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have an array. I am looping over that. First what I need is that when the loop is run first it should already open up a div and add text to it. Next I want that if a loop has run 3 times then close the previous div and open a new div.

Code:

```
var counter = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < tag_array.length; i++) {
    counter++;
    if (counter == 3) {
        counter = 0;
        document.write("</div>");
        document.write("<div class='span6'>");
    } else {
        document.write("<div class='span6'>");
    }
    document.write("<div class='tag'>" + toTitleCase(tag_array[i]) + "</div>");
}
```

The above code is not working. I don't know why. Please explain me what I am doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try to find the point where it does not work.  List the things that you want it to do (which you did) and then figure out exactly where things go wrong.  What does "not working" even mean?  Are the divs even being created?  Are you making too many divs?  Are the divs not being closed?

Comment: You don't need `counter`, just do `if (i % 3 == 0)`.

Comment: @JustinL "not working" means that the div having the class "span6" is not getting closed after every 3 iteration and also a new div having a class "span6" is not opening.

Comment: you have a lot of unclosed `<div>`s

Comment: Instead of using document.write every time you should just create one big HTML string and use document.write when you're done with the loop.

Comment: [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) could be a good option if you need to manipulate the DOM.

Comment: Did you get your code to work?

Answer (score 3):

> when the loop is run first it should already open up a div and add text to it. Next I want that if a loop has run 3 times then close the previous div and open a new div.

The reason why you are doing it wrong is because `else { document.write("<div class='span6'>");}` will cause `document.write` even when counter is 2.

So you should change it to `else if(counter == 1)`:

```
var counter = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < tag_array.length; i++) {
    //this line indicates that the counter will only be either 1,2,3 when it enters the if statement
    counter++;
    if(counter == 3){
        counter = 0;
        document.write("</div>");
    }else if(counter == 1){
        document.write("<div class='span6'>");
    }
    document.write("<div class='tag'>" + toTitleCase(tag_array[i]) + "</div>");
}
```

To make it look less confusing you can change the if statement to a switch statement, have `counter++;` in the switch statement and make the for statement into a while statement:

```
var counter = 0;
var i = 0;
var length = tag_array.length;
while (i <length) {
    switch(counter){
        case 2:
        document.write("</div>");
        //when counter reaches 2, set it back to 0 and leave the switch statement;
        counter = 0;
        break;
        case 0:
        document.write("<div class='span6'>");
        case 1:
        //counter++ will only be triggered when counter is 1 or 0;
        counter++;
    }
    document.write("<div class='tag'>" + toTitleCase(tag_array[i]) + "</div>");
    i++;
}
```

Or if you want to be more efficient you can use the codes below. (Inspired by [frenchie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19071717/2041954). I corrected his answer to one that works properly.*If you want to upvote or accept this answer because of the codes below, please upvote or accept [his](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19071717/2041954) instead.*)

```
var a = '<div class="span6">';

var length = tag_array.length;

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {


  a += '<div class="tag">' + toTitleCase(tag_array[i]) + '</div>';

 if (i % 3 == 2) {

      a += '</div><div class="span6">';
  }

}

a += '</div>';

document.write(a);
```

Comment: This is soooo inefficient and convoluted! Look at my answer and compare.

Comment: @frenchie Yours doesn't do what OP wants to do. Compare my latest answer with yours. Upvote instead of downvote mine if it is better and it does what OP wants to do. Thank you.

Comment: @frenchie Read carefully. I didn't copy your codes. And I turn them into the way OP wants it to work.

Comment: Oh yes, instead of concatenating TheHTML = TheHTML + ... you changed it to a +=... Unbelievable!!!!!! 40 minutes after your answer you /copy my code, change variable names and make a ridiculous syntax change????

Comment: @frenchie Mine is `(i % 3 === 2)` and its position is different from your `if (i % 3 === 0)` which won't work as the way OP wants it.

Comment: Whatever, you cheated because if you hadn't seen my answer, your answer was BS for 40 minutes. The edit history of your answer proves my point.

Comment: YOU CHEATED but I agree with you on the position of the conditional check.

Comment: @frenchie You downvoted me and inspired me to write a faster algorithm for it. How is it cheating? And it should be `===2`. The statement `if (i % 3 === 0)` will run when the loop first started and that is not what OP wants.

Comment: You cheated because you copied my code, fixed the logic bug that was in it (I agree with you on that) and then claimed it yours while what was actually yours was some awfully inefficient code that had nothing to do with the final answer you're proposing. I'm leaving my answer as for people to see, compare and make their own judgment about what you did.

Comment: @frenchie I was helping OP to understand where he gets it wrong. So I only intended to modify his codes as little as possible such that he can understand exactly why his one didn't work. After you downvoted me I realized I should actually write a more efficient one for OP, and one that works, not like yours. It was inspired by yours but i didn't copy and paste yours.

Comment: Don't you think the honest approach would have been to comment on my answer about the bug?

Comment: @frenchie Don't you think a more mature approach would have been not to walk around down-voting answer that you don't like but is correct and telling people to "Look at my answer and compare"? Then when other people provide a solution that resembles yours but is different from yours because it actually works, don't you think a more mature approach would have been to reflect on it and learn not to tell others to "Look at my answer and compare" before checking if your own answer is correct instead of accusing others of cheating and stealing your idea?

Comment: That doesn't answer the question I asked you and in fact just reinforces my point: you were dishonest in how you handled your answer and you're now looking to throw tomatoes. No no no non mon ami: your initial answer sucked (which is why I downvoted it) and then you copied my answer and fixed it. That was dishonest and I think most people would agree with me on that.

Comment: @frenchie It depends on how you define "dishonest". I didn't copy your codes. What I used was your idea and I modified it. So if turning other people's idea into a better one is a crime, then have fun living with this concept and thinking that the world is unfair to you.  My initial answer was to help OP to understand where he got wrong. That's all. And yours doesn't even work properly.

Comment: You see, I used the comment provided by GG (comment is 2nd in question) to CREATE my answer and that's what's called being inspired.  You on the other hand COPIED my answer and then fixed the bug and claimed it yours. That's the difference. And BTW, I'm not here "claiming the world is unfair" like you're suggesting; that's your opinion and it's not the point I'm addressing.

Comment: Anyway, all this is pretty mute anyway. I do give you credit for having fixed my answer and therefore answering the OP's question. In the future, I recommend you show more integrity in dealing with people's intellectual property because in other circles this behavior would have had you set. Have a good night.

Comment: @frenchie please edit yours and correct the codes so I can remove mine too. Good evening.

Comment: @frenchie And if you still think that your answer is so unique that nobody would have thought of it, please get it patented before posting. Like what I've said, my initial intention was to help OP. That doesn't mean I'm a retard who can't write efficient codes. You just happened to come up with the most efficient solution first. And then you tell me to compare my codes with yours, and I saw your solution and I really like your idea so I modified it and made it work. That doesn't mean I won't be able to come up with the same idea if I didn't see yours first.

Comment: That approach is not very uncommon and is not of complexity. Everyone who knows a bit of programming and likes to think a lot will eventually be able to come up with the idea of having everything in a string first and manipulating the string before `document.write()` it. If what you've come up with is something complex and uncommon, then I won't modify it a bit and call it my creation inspired by the original. Instead, I will respect it from the bottom of my heart and consider it as your intellectual property. As in this case it will be justifiable to say that is a creation of yours.

Comment: I don't care man, it's an answer on Stack. You can cut and dice it any way you want but in the end, the edit history of your post tells a story.

Answer (score 1):

You were opening another `span` and not closing it with every iteration, so you should take the first span out of the loop.

This should work, I also added another `</div>` at the end of the loop

```
var counter = 0;
document.write("<div class='span6'>");
for (i = 0; i < tag_array.length; i++) {
    if (counter === 3) {
        counter = 0;
        document.write("</div>");
        document.write("<div class='span6'>");
    }

    document.write("<div class='tag'>" + toTitleCase(tag_array[i]) + "</div>");
    counter++;
    if (i === tag_array.length - 1) {
        document.write("</div>")
    }
}
```